# Splunk custom alert Python issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, splunk

I am running the following code (called caa_fiel_write.py) to output my splunk results to a JSON file:

```
import sys, json, urllib2
def write_file(settings):
        f = open('myfile','w')
        f.write("%s"%json.dumps(settings))
        f.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
        caa_config = json.loads(sys.stdin.read())
        write_file(caa_config)
```

I get the following errors:

---

File "/opt/sdg/splunk/etc/apps/SDG/bin/caa_file_write.py", line 7, in 
     caa_config = json.loads(sys.stdin.read())

File "/opt/sdg/splunk/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
     return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "/opt/sdg/splunk/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
   obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "/opt/sdg/splunk/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
     raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

---

Line 339 from __init__.py is:

```
   return _default_decoder.decode(s)
```

Lines 364 and 382 from decoder.py are:

```
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
...
        raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

I am not sure why it is calling the decoder in the first place, it should be encoding. Both the __init__.py and decoder.py are standard Splunk python files which are available through any distribution.

**What are these errors and how do I fix them?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.loads(sys.stdin.read())` is decoding standard input. Your input is not valid JSON.

Comment: so the input has to be valid JSON?

Comment: @Deesbek yes, what did you expect?

Comment: LOL, I was expecting a conversion, standard key/value pairs to JSON, but now that I actually re-read the chapter in the book it is behaving as expected.